# About the norm in $C^{\ell, \alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$.

Tags: functional-analysis, holder-spaces

In my functional analysis course, we defined for $\ell \in \mathbb N$ and $\alpha \in (0, 1]$,
\begin{align*}
C^{\ell, \alpha}(\Omega) &= \left\{u \in C^\ell(\Omega)~\bigg|~ \max_{|\beta| = \ell}\sup_{x \neq y \in \Omega} \frac{|\partial^\beta u(x) - \partial^\beta u(y)|}{|x - y|^\alpha} < +\infty\right\},\\
C^{\ell, \alpha}(\overline{\Omega}) &= \left\{u ~\bigg|~ \exists U \text{ open }, \overline{\Omega} \subset U, u \in C^{\ell, \alpha}(U)\right\}.
\end{align*}
For $\Omega$ bounded, my teacher said (an Wikipedia agreed) that these sets are Banach spaces with respect to the norm
$$\|u\|_{C^{\ell, \alpha}} = \max_{|\beta| \le \ell}\|\partial^\beta u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} + \max_{|\beta| = \ell}\sup_{x \neq y \in \Omega} \frac{|\partial^\beta(x) - \partial^\beta(y)|}{|x - y|^\alpha}.$$
But on $C^{\ell, \alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$, I don't see why $\|\cdot\|_{C^{\ell, \alpha}}$ is even a norm. Indeed, for $\ell = 0, \alpha = 1$ and $\overline{\Omega} = [0, 1]$, we can take
$$
u(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x \in (-1, 1],\\
x - 1 & \text{if } x \in (1, 2).
\end{cases}
$$
If I am not mistaken, $u \in C^{0,1}((-1, 2))$ and $\|u\|_{C^{0, 1}} = 0$ but $u \neq 0$. Perhaps we should consider $\|u\|_{C^{0, 1}(U)}$ but now I'm not sure that everything is well-defined since for one $u$ there could be $\overline{\Omega} \subset U_1 \neq U_2$ open such that $\|u\|_{C^{0, 1}(U_1)} \neq \|u\|_{C^{0, 1}(U_1)}$.

Comment: I don't think $||u||_{C^{0,1}}=0$ in your exemple. Indeed you can see that $$||u||_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq ||u||_{C^{0,1}}$$ and clearly $||u||_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$ is different from zero. (if $l=0$, you still have a contribution from $\max_{|\beta| \le \ell}\|\partial^\beta u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$, for $\beta=0$)

Comment: But 
$$\|u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} = \sup_{x \in \Omega}|u(x)|$$
right ? Since $\Omega = (-1, 1)$ and $u =  0$ on $\Omega$, the norm should be zero (?)

Comment: Oh okay my mistake, let me think a bit.

Comment: I don't understant. Since $\ell = 0,$ the norm will be 
$$\|u\|_{C^{0,1}} = \sup_{x \in (0, 1)} |u(x)| + |u|_{0,1}$$
where $|u|_{0,1}$ is the quotient. Aren't both terms equal to zero in my example ?

Comment: Okay, using your notation, $||u||_{C^{0,1}(0,1)}=0$ right ? So you are telling that $u|_{(0,1)} \in C^{0,1}(0,1)$ , and furthermore $u|_{(0,1)}=0$. The value you put to $u$ outside of $(0,1)$ don't change anything, I think there is a confusion between $u$ and $u|_{(0,1)}$.

Comment: However, if you look at $||u||_{C^{0,1}(-1,2)}$, then it is not zero with my first comments.